# Combining multidimensional arrays in php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

### What I am trying

I have 2 arrays as shown below:

Array 1:

```
Array
(
 [38] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [code] => ACC
                [amount] => 50
                [emp_number] => 38
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [code] => CAR
                [amount] => 60
                [emp_number] => 38
            )

    )

[22] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [code] => ACC
                [amount] => 110
                [emp_number] => 22
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [code] => AIR
                [amount] => 260
                [emp_number] => 22
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [code] => CAP
                [amount] => 205
                [emp_number] => 22
            )
      )

 )
```

Array2:

```
 Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [code] => ACC
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [code] => AIR
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [code] => ARC
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [code] => ATV
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [code] => CAP
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [code] => CAR
    )

)
```

### What I Want

Final Array:

```
   Array
(
 [38] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [code] => ACC
                [amount] => 50
                [emp_number] => 38
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [code] => AIR
                [amount] => ''
                [emp_number] => 38
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [code] => ARC
                [amount] => ''
                [emp_number] => 38
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [code] => ATV
                [amount] => ''
                [emp_number] => 38
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [code] => CAP
                [amount] => ''
                [emp_number] => 38
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [code] => CAR
                [amount] => 60
                [emp_number] => 38
            )

    )

[22] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [code] => ACC
                [amount] => 110
                [emp_number] => 22
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [code] => AIR
                [amount] => 260
                [emp_number] => 22
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [code] => ARC
                [amount] => ''
                [emp_number] => 22
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [code] => ATV
                [amount] => ''
                [emp_number] => 22
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [code] => CAP
                [amount] => 205
                [emp_number] => 22
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [code] => CAR
                [amount] => ''
                [emp_number] => 22
            )
      )

 )
```

### Code

```
 $count = count($category);
    $exp = array();
    foreach ($expItem as $empItem) {
        $j = 0;
        foreach ($category as $cat) {
            foreach ($empItem as $emp) {
                for ($k = 0; $k < $count; $k++) {
                    if ($emp['code'] == $category['code']) {
                        $expItem[$emp['emp_number']][$k]['name'] = $category[$k]['name'];
                    } else {
                        $expItem[$emp['emp_number']][$k]['code'] = $category[$k]['code'];
                        $expItem[$emp['emp_number']][$k]['name'] = $category[$k]['name'];
                    }
                }
            }
            $j++;
        }
    }
```

Here `$expItem` is the first array and `$category` is the second array and I'm getting final array in `$expItem` itself. `$emp['emp_number']` is the cell key of first array '38' and '22'. Its available in first array along with `code` and `amount`. The `$category` also contains value `name`

How can I combine the 2 arrays so that I can get the final array correctly?

**EDIT:** The code in first array is same as that in second array. Second array contains all codes and respective names. First array shows employee data where it shows how much amount is there for code which employee used. What I want is if employee hasn't used any code then the first array should show the corresponding code and amount as 0 in employee data. The codes are dynamically achieved so cannot hardcode them.

Comment: It's somewhat unclear to me what you're asking. Can you describe in a very simple sentence what the relationship of the first and the second array is? I don't really see it.

Comment: Is it correct to say that you want to *augment* the first array so that all codes from the second array are added to it if they're not already in there? It also looks like the numeric keys of the first array are irrelevant?

Comment: can you show all the keys(e.g emp_number) of both arrays? whats the output when you run your code?

Comment: Which version of PHP you are using?

Comment: @AshishChoudhary: 5.4

Comment: if it would have been 5.5, I would have a simpler code. Nevermind. i will jsut post the solution as an answer

Comment: Great job invalidating our effort by moving the goal post. :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this one? $result will have the expected array.

```
$result = [];

foreach($expItem as $key => $item) {

    $result[$key] = array_map(function($value) use ($key, $item){
        $value['amount'] = '';
        $value['emp_number'] = $key;

        foreach($item as $_key => $_item) {
            if($_item['code'] === $value['code']) {
                $value['amount'] = $_item['amount'];
            }
        }

        return $value;

    }, $category);

}
```

Comment: Yes it's correct, Change this line`$result[] = array_map(function($value) use ($key, $item){` to `$result[$key] = array_map(function($value) use ($key, $item){` to get the final output as you want.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$arr_final = array();
foreach($array1 as $key1=>$item_arr1){
    $arr_temp = array();
    foreach($array2 as $key2=>$item_arr2){
        foreach($item_arr1 as $key3=>$item_arr3){
            if($item_arr3['code'] == $item_arr2['code']){
                $arr_temp[$key2]['code'] = $item_arr3['code'];
                $arr_temp[$key2]['amount'] = $item_arr3['amount'];
            }
        }
        if(!isset($arr_temp[$key2]['code'])){
            $arr_temp[$key2]['code'] = $item_arr2['code'];
            $arr_temp[$key2]['amount'] = '';
        }
    }
    $arr_final[] = $arr_temp;
}
print_r($arr_final);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this:

```
<?php
$arr1 = array(38 => array(array('code'    =>  'ACC', 'amount' => 50), 
                          array('code'    =>  'CAR', 'amount' => 60)),
              22 => array(array('code'    =>  'ACC', 'amount' => 110), 
                          array('code'    =>  'AIR', 'amount' => 260),
                          array('code'    =>  'CAP', 'amount' => 205)));

$arr2 = array(array('code'  =>  'ACC'), array('code'  =>  'AIR'),
              array('code'  =>  'ARC'), array('code'  =>  'ATV'),
              array('code'  =>  'CAP'),array('code'  =>  'CAR'));
$outputArr = array();
$arrModified = array_values($arr1);
$arrayCount1 = count($arrModified);
$arrayCount2 = count($arr2);
for ($i = 0; $i < $arrayCount1; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < $arrayCount2; $j++) {
        $outputArr[$i][$j]['code'] = $arr2[$j]['code'];
        $outputArr[$i][$j]['amount'] = '';
        $tempArrCount = count($arrModified[$i]);
        for ($k = 0; $k < $tempArrCount; $k++) {
            if ($arrModified[$i][$k]['code'] == $outputArr[$i][$j]['code']) {
                $outputArr[$i][$j]['amount'] = $arrModified[$i][$k]['amount'];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($outputArr);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$exp = array();
foreach ($expItems as $key => $empItem) {
    foreach ($category as $key2 => $cat) {
        foreach ($empItem as $emp) {
            if ($emp['code'] == $cat['code']) {
                $finalArray[$key][$key2] = $emp;
            }
        }
        if(!isset($finalArray[$key][$key2])){
            $finalArray[$key][] = array(
                'code' => $cat['code'],
                'amount' => '',
            );
        }
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($finalArray);
```